# Send go test coverage output to stdout - send it to S3

Tags: go, amazon-s3, go-testing

I want to send the html for `go test -c` to stdout, so I can serve the resulting HTML from S3 static assets server.

Something like this:

```
arti_fact="s3://cm-html/cm-api/$commit_sha"

go test -coverprofile cover.out .
go tool cover -html=cover.out -o /dev/stdout  | aws s3 cp - "$arti_fact"
```

is there a way to write to stdout without using `-o /dev/stdout`?

Comment: It writes to stdout by default. Stop passing `-o`.

Comment: it doesn't... `go tool cover -html=cover.out` opens a web browser

Comment: Can you clarify the question then? You're commenting about `go tool cover` but your question asks about `go test`.

Comment: i may have updated the question right before you commented, refresh page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way to send golang code coverage info to S3 / GCS is like so:

```
go test -coverprofile cover.out .
go tool cover -html=cover.out -o /dev/stdout  | gsutil cp - gs://my-bucket/foo
```

if there is a way to do it without a temporary file, that would be nice. Something like:

```
go test -coverprofile '/dev/stdout'  | 
go tool cover -html='/dev/stdin' -o '/dev/stdout'  | 
gsutil cp - 'gs://my-bucket/foo'
```